# How do I set a conditional breakpoint in Netbeans 8.2 C++

Tags: c++, debugging, netbeans, conditional-statements, breakpoints

I have a counter, sampleCount, and I want the debugger to stop when it is equal to 180. I set up this

[image]

but when I run it, the program does not stop.  Is there someplace that explains the syntax and function of the various fields in that dialog? Or can someone give me a quick description.  I tried >180, ==180.
Thanks

Comment: Try `sampleCount == 180` or similar.  The condition needs to be a boolean expression, I think.

Comment: Thanks Paul.  It didn't work.  Code stops every time sampleCount changes.

Comment: I found it.  I was setting a "Variable" breakpoint.  If I set a "Line number" breakpoint, then I can add the condition as you mention Paul, and it works.  I'm not sure how to use the "Variable" type breakpoint but I don't need it at this point.  I hope this will help others....

Comment: Looks like you can't.  I know that Visual Studio works this way.